# AspectJ execution pointcut on same method throwing NPE

Tags: aspectj

Consider the following naive aspect:

```java
package utils;

import org.aspectj.lang.*;
import org.aspectj.lang.annotation.*;

import lombok.extern.slf4j.*;

/**
 * TBD
 */
@Aspect
@Slf4j
public class DiagnosticsAspect {

    @Around("selfTestExecution()") // ******** 1st around aspect
    @SuppressWarnings("static-method")
    public Object aroundSelfTest(
        final ProceedingJoinPoint thisJoinPoint)
        throws Throwable {
        log.debug("before");
        try {
            log.debug("thisJoinPoint {}", thisJoinPoint);
            log.debug("args {}", thisJoinPoint.getArgs());
            return thisJoinPoint.proceed(thisJoinPoint.getArgs());
        } finally {
            log.debug("after");
        }
    }

    @Around("selfTestExecution2()") // ******** 2nd around aspect
    @SuppressWarnings("static-method")
    public Object aroundSelfTest2(
        final ProceedingJoinPoint thisJoinPoint)
        throws Throwable {
        log.debug("before2");
        try {
            log.debug("thisJoinPoint2 {}", thisJoinPoint);
            log.debug("args2 {}", thisJoinPoint.getArgs());
            return thisJoinPoint.proceed(thisJoinPoint.getArgs());
        } finally {
            log.debug("after2");
        }
    }

    @Pointcut("execution(void DiagnosticsAspect.selfTest())")
    public void selfTestExecution() {
        // nothing to do here -- just defines a pointcut matcher
    }

    @Pointcut("execution(void DiagnosticsAspect.selfTest())")
    public void selfTestExecution2() {
        // nothing to do here -- just defines a pointcut matcher
    }

    public static void selfTest() {
        log.debug("self test");
        throw new AssertionError("there was an error");
    }
}
```

and this test:

```java
public class DiagnosticsAspectTest {

    @Test
    public void testSelfTest() {
        DiagnosticsAspect.selfTest();
    }
}
```

It ends with following console printout:

```
21:43:13.568 [DEBUG] [main]: DiagnosticsAspect - before
21:43:13.570 [DEBUG] [main]: DiagnosticsAspect - thisJoinPoint execution(void utils.DiagnosticsAspect.selfTest())
21:43:13.571 [DEBUG] [main]: DiagnosticsAspect - args {}
21:43:13.572 [DEBUG] [main]: DiagnosticsAspect - before2
21:43:13.572 [DEBUG] [main]: DiagnosticsAspect - thisJoinPoint2 execution(void utils.DiagnosticsAspect.selfTest())
21:43:13.572 [DEBUG] [main]: DiagnosticsAspect - args2 {}
21:43:13.572 [DEBUG] [main]: DiagnosticsAspect - self test
21:43:13.572 [DEBUG] [main]: DiagnosticsAspect - after2
21:43:13.573 [DEBUG] [main]: DiagnosticsAspect - after

java.lang.NullPointerException 
  at utils.DiagnosticsAspect.selfTest(DiagnosticsAspect.java:56) 
  at utils.DiagnosticsAspectTest.testSelfTest(DiagnosticsAspectTest.java:9)
  at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) 
  at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
  at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) 
  at org.testng.internal.MethodInvocationHelper.invokeMethod(MethodInvocationHelper.java:124)
  at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeMethod(Invoker.java:583) 
  at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeTestMethod(Invoker.java:719) 
  at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeTestMethods(Invoker.java:989) 
  at org.testng.internal.TestMethodWorker.invokeTestMethods(TestMethodWorker.java:125)
  at org.testng.internal.TestMethodWorker.run(TestMethodWorker.java:109)
  at org.testng.TestRunner.privateRun(TestRunner.java:648) 
  at org.testng.TestRunner.run(TestRunner.java:505) 
  at org.testng.SuiteRunner.runTest(SuiteRunner.java:455) 
  at org.testng.SuiteRunner.runSequentially(SuiteRunner.java:450) 
  at org.testng.SuiteRunner.privateRun(SuiteRunner.java:415) 
  at org.testng.SuiteRunner.run(SuiteRunner.java:364) 
  at org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.runSuite(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:52) 
  at org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.run(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:84) 
  at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesSequentially(TestNG.java:1208) 
  at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesLocally(TestNG.java:1137) 
  at org.testng.TestNG.runSuites(TestNG.java:1049) 
  at org.testng.TestNG.run(TestNG.java:1017) 
  at com.intellij.rt.testng.IDEARemoteTestNG.run(IDEARemoteTestNG.java:66)
  at com.intellij.rt.testng.RemoteTestNGStarter.main(RemoteTestNGStarter.java:110)
  at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) 
  at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
  at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) 
  at com.intellij.rt.execution.CommandLineWrapper.main(CommandLineWrapper.java:64)

===============================================
Default Suite Total tests run: 1, Failures: 1, Skips: 0
===============================================
```

Tried to setup an NPE breakpoint and the debugger stops on `log.debug("self test");`.
This happens only if the 2nd around aspect exists.

Any suggestions?

Comment: What do you mean "this happens only if the 2nd around aspect exists"? It does not look like any aspect is being executed.

Comment: Edited and added the full console printout. The aspects are executed and executed fine. Issue exists if the instrumented method 1) throws an exception and 2) is advised by two aspects -- so if you comment out the 2nd aspect then the correct exception is thrown (AssertionError). If no exception is thrown then both aspects work fine :)

Comment: I analysed the problem locally and then remembered that I had seen the same thing before here on SO and reported an AspectJ bug. Just upgrade to 1.9.5 and be happy. I tried, it solves your problem. And please next time post console logs or stack traces as code blocks, not as quoted text. I reformatted your question and the stack trace first so I could recognise more. Adding syntax highlighting to your question also is a good idea for better readability. Just look how I did it and learn from it or read the formatting help. Thank you very much.